# Runtime Warning in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-timezone

I am working on a Django project with MySQL as the back-end, this warning keeps troubling me, can anyone please suggest a fix for this. Thanks in advance!!

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808: 
    RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-04-22 10:34:44) 
    while time zone support is active.
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to make the following changes:

In settings.py, you need to add following line:

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Also, in your code you should create `aware` datetime objects:

eg:

Instead of

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

You should do:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

now_time = now()
```

This will make use of USE_TZ from `settings.py` and will create `aware` datetime objects instead of `native`.

You should read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: Another solution being to NOT use timezone-aware datetimes, ie set settings.USE_TZ to False.