# Runtime warning

Tags: python, django

I use

```
python manage.py dumpdata --format yaml > test.yaml
```

In **test.yaml** I have something like that:

```
- fields: {test1: "my test", date: !!timestamp '2014-03-20 02:08:28+00:00', date_updated: !!timestamp '2014-03-20
      02:08:28+00:00', test: true,}
```

Then I use:

```
python manage.py loaddata test
```

In logs I see:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Test.date received a naive datetime (2014-03-20 06:08:28) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

In models I have:

```
Class Test(models.Model):
    # many fields
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False,)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True,)
```

How to fix that warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139824/runtime-warning-in-django?rq=1

Comment: I think this is a closer duplicate, saying the problem is in PyYAML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462634/loaddata-not-dealing-with-timestamps-and-timezones-properly

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.

Shut off timezone support in your site settings. Option is `USE_TZ`.

The second option is to make sure you're using a time zone aware datetime object when you insert your datetime into the database. Django includes a timezone class that creates timezone aware datetime objects.

Relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: I dont want shut off timezone support. I understand,  that I must edit ```date``` and ```date_updated```, but how?

Comment: And I have ```RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Session.expire_date received a naive datetime (2014-04-03 14:07:42) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)```. And many-many others.